# How can I get a jar from kotlin code if I don't use classes?

Tags: java, kotlin, compilation

I want to make a jar of a couple of .kt files which contains code that are functions. I don't have classes. My directory looks like this.

```
src
|--- myPackage
|      |--- fileone.kt
|      |--- filetwo.kt
|--- myMainFile.kt
```

myMainFile.kt calls functions from myPackage. I'm interested in generating a jar using the command line.

I used `kotlinc myMainFile.kt myPackage -include-runtime -d myRunnable.jar` and it did generate `myRunnable.jar` however it didn't work when I tried to run it. I get the following error message :
`no main manifest attribute, in myRunnable.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin will generate class for you. It will be named MyMainFileKt.

So, to make jar runnable, you will need to provide META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file with the following content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MyMainFileKt
```

Comment: What command do I write once I've made the MANIFEST.MF file?

Comment: Assuming that `META-INF` folder with `MANIFEST.MF` file inside is placed next to myMainFile.kt: `kotlinc myMainFile.kt myPackage META-INF -include-runtime -d myRunnable.jar`